# Nginx is not serving Django static files

Tags: django, file, static, nginx

I just configured my first django server for a very basic django-website. I'm using Django 1.4 and Nginx 1.0.14 with supervisor and gunicorn.

The problem is that Nginx is not serving the static files as suposed, but I don't know the why because is my first time using it.

This is the path where really lives my static files:

```
/home/cristian/envs/santalupe.com/santalupe/santalupe/static
```

And this is the setting I've in my nginx config file:

```
# Django admin media.
location /media/ {
autoindex on;
    alias /home/cristian/envs/santalupe.com/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/;
}

# Site media
location /static/ {
autoindex on;
    alias /home/cristian/envs/santalupe.com/santalupe/santalupe/static/;
}
```

Please let me know what I need to do in this case because I have not idea about the real problem.

Comment: Are you just getting 404s? Are those rules above or below your `location /` in the nginx config?

Comment: I'm getting 404s. The rules are above of 'location /'

Comment: And the files are definitely in that folder? Is nginx correctly passing normal connections onto the application server?

Comment: Yes, my static files are in that folder. The other things about Nginx are working good, I thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't serving the admin media from Nginx, just normal media. Try something like:

```
location /admin/media/ {
    # this changes depending on your python version
    root /home/cristian/envs/santalupe.com/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib;
}
```

Note how there's no trailing slash and the path ends at contrib. I'm using almost exactly this code successfully in production.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [manage.py collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/#collectstatic) on server help you?

Comment: Did'n worked for me, I just ran this command and reseted the project and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Here is good description on right solution https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-production